# How can I convert this VB.NET code to C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates

How can I convert this VB.NET code to C#?

```
Private myImageMapCalculations As New clsImageMapCalculations(Sub(ex As Exception) UnhandledExceptionHandler())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
private clsImageMapCalculations myImageMapCalculations = 
new clsImageMapCalculations((Exception ex) => UnhandledExceptionHandler());
```

The part that can create problems with a conversion tool is :

```
Sub(ex As Exception) UnhandledExceptionHandler()
```

that can be converted into a corresponding lambda expression in C# :

```
(Exception ex) => UnhandledExceptionHandler()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private clsImageMapCalculations myImageMapCalculations = new clsImageMapCalculations((Exception ex) => UnhandledExceptionHandler());
```

VB.NET to C# conversions can be done by convertion tools, for example see http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/